# ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ChartModule' was called

Tags: typescript, angular5, smartadmin

I installed `angular2-highcharts` on my Angular Project, implemented that. Its working but in `ng serve` mode. But when I executed the command `ng build --prod`. I got the error :

**Error during template compile of `AppModule`**

**Function calls are not supported in decorators but `ChartModule` was called.**

Its working fine when i executed `ng build`.

Here is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic }  from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

declare var require : any;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,HttpModule,
    ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts/highstock'),require('highcharts/modules/drilldown')),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Had you solved this problem? I run into this issue today with an NPM module that wrote by me.

Comment: @zixia I just removed the require declaration and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are not allowed to do any function calls inside of the forRoot function.

Similar issue was discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9358